# SVN server - host OS in place update

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, svn

I have a SVN server (Apache Web Server included) installed on Windows Server 2003 host. There's no other service installed. Only file server capabilities.
I need to update the host OS. I need to move to Server 2008 R2 but it has to be an in-place update. Same machine - simply update OS.

I know that SVN supports Server 2008 R2, but I don't know if this in-place update might damage anything associated to SVN.

Has anybody seen something like this or had some experience in this matter? 
Is there any documentation about this subject?

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid that your subversion repository will be messed up, I suggest you `dump` it into a file. You can then `load` that dump later on in case anything went wrong.

See [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html) for more information.